# How do I (recursively?) monitor contents of new directories using inotify?

Tags: c, unix, directory, inotify

Firstly, I want to start by using inotify to monitor a specific directory (the main directory) for files and sub-directories. If a new directory is added into this main directory, how would I make sure to monitor this sub-directory with inotify? How would I monitor a new directory within this sub-directory of the main directory?

I think adding it to the watch is easy by using the `inotify_add_watch()` function but I do not know how to get the correct relative path address of files and directories within sub-directories (to use for like Dropbox-like syncing in a different location while maintaining the correct directory tree, for example).

Comment: The code is given here by me.please check it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147757/inotify-recursively-how-to-do-it/27917793#27917793

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the fastest to implement (but not the fastest in reality) would be to:

1. Create the initial tree of directories by recursively exploring the children; An example in C/Linux can be found here:

   http://www.lemoda.net/c/recursive-directory/
2. Add a watch for each subdirectory; When something has been modified or changed you can parse all children recursively and see the differences. Something similar was discussed here:
   [How to monitor a folder with all subfolders and files inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067175/how-to-monitor-a-folder-with-all-subfolders-and-files-inside)
3. If this solution doesn't appeal to you, you might try to do a polling mechanism such that you must re-check the whole structure using a thread at a certain time interval.

Hope it helps!